# what is the right way to install ansible on rhel machines 7.6 version

Tags: rhel, python, yum, repository, ansible

we want to installs the `ansible` OFF-LINE on rhel 7.6 machine ( refrence - https://www.linuxschoolonline.com/how-to-install-ansible-offline-on-centos-or-redhat/ )

Ansible needs the following prerequisites to be present on the system

```
python-crypto
python-httplib
python-jinja2
python-keyczar
sshpass
```

so we install by yum all the requested rpm's

as we can see its failed about

```
Error: Package: python-keyczar-0.71c-8.mga7.noarch (/python-keyczar-0.71c-8.mga7.noarch)
           Requires: python2.7dist(pyasn1)
Error: Package: python-keyczar-0.71c-8.mga7.noarch (/python-keyczar-0.71c-8.mga7.noarch)
           Requires: python2.7dist(pycrypto) > 2.0
```

just note - we are registered to redhat 7.x repository
and we not sure from where we need to take the missing rpm's , and why rhel repo not include all required rpm's ?

what is the suggestion to installed all these required rpm's?

```
yum localinstall -y  python-keyczar-0.71c-2.el7.noarch.rpm  sshpass-1.06-2.el7.x86_64.rpm python2-crypto-2.6.1-15.el7.x86_64.rpm python-httplib2-0.9.2-1.el7.noarch.rpm python-jinja2-2.7.2-4.el7.noarch.rpm python-keyczar-0.71c-8.mga7.noarch.rpm

Loaded plugins: langpacks, product-id, search-disabled-repos, subscription-manager
Examining python-keyczar-0.71c-2.el7.noarch.rpm: python-keyczar-0.71c-2.el7.noarch
Marking python-keyczar-0.71c-2.el7.noarch.rpm to be installed
Examining sshpass-1.06-2.el7.x86_64.rpm: sshpass-1.06-2.el7.x86_64
sshpass-1.06-2.el7.x86_64.rpm: does not update installed package.
Examining python2-crypto-2.6.1-15.el7.x86_64.rpm: python2-crypto-2.6.1-15.el7.x86_64
Marking python2-crypto-2.6.1-15.el7.x86_64.rpm to be installed
Examining python-httplib2-0.9.2-1.el7.noarch.rpm: python-httplib2-0.9.2-1.el7.noarch
Marking python-httplib2-0.9.2-1.el7.noarch.rpm as an update to python-httplib2-0.9.1-2.1.el7.noarch
Examining python-jinja2-2.7.2-4.el7.noarch.rpm: python-jinja2-2.7.2-4.el7.noarch
Marking python-jinja2-2.7.2-4.el7.noarch.rpm as an update to python-jinja2-2.7.2-3.el7_6.noarch
Examining python-keyczar-0.71c-8.mga7.noarch.rpm: python-keyczar-0.71c-8.mga7.noarch
Marking python-keyczar-0.71c-8.mga7.noarch.rpm to be installed
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package python-httplib2.noarch 0:0.9.1-2.1.el7 will be updated
---> Package python-httplib2.noarch 0:0.9.2-1.el7 will be an update
---> Package python-jinja2.noarch 0:2.7.2-3.el7_6 will be updated
---> Package python-jinja2.noarch 0:2.7.2-4.el7 will be an update
---> Package python-keyczar.noarch 0:0.71c-2.el7 will be installed
---> Package python-keyczar.noarch 0:0.71c-8.mga7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: python2.7dist(pycrypto) > 2.0 for package: python-keyczar-0.71c-8.mga7.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: python2.7dist(pyasn1) for package: python-keyczar-0.71c-8.mga7.noarch
---> Package python2-crypto.x86_64 0:2.6.1-15.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libtomcrypt.so.0()(64bit) for package: python2-crypto-2.6.1-15.el7.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package libtomcrypt.x86_64 0:1.17-26.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libtommath >= 0.42.0 for package: libtomcrypt-1.17-26.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libtommath.so.0()(64bit) for package: libtomcrypt-1.17-26.el7.x86_64
---> Package python-keyczar.noarch 0:0.71c-8.mga7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: python2.7dist(pycrypto) > 2.0 for package: python-keyczar-0.71c-8.mga7.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: python2.7dist(pyasn1) for package: python-keyczar-0.71c-8.mga7.noarch
--> Running transaction check
---> Package libtommath.x86_64 0:0.42.0-6.el7 will be installed
---> Package python-keyczar.noarch 0:0.71c-8.mga7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: python2.7dist(pycrypto) > 2.0 for package: python-keyczar-0.71c-8.mga7.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: python2.7dist(pyasn1) for package: python-keyczar-0.71c-8.mga7.noarch
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: python-keyczar-0.71c-8.mga7.noarch (/python-keyczar-0.71c-8.mga7.noarch)
           Requires: python2.7dist(pyasn1)
Error: Package: python-keyczar-0.71c-8.mga7.noarch (/python-keyczar-0.71c-8.mga7.noarch)
           Requires: python2.7dist(pycrypto) > 2.0
**********************************************************************
yum can be configured to try to resolve such errors by temporarily enabling
disabled repos and searching for missing dependencies.
To enable this functionality please set 'notify_only=0' in /etc/yum/pluginconf.d/search-disabled-repos.conf
**********************************************************************
```

Comment: Which direction is this post going? The word "offline" implies that you are *disconnected* from the RHEL repositories; it's reinforced by the fact that you've downloaded RPMs and are running "yum localinstall".  I suggest editing the Q to remove the distracting "why rhel repo not include all required rpms?".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’re trying to install two versions of `python-keyczar`, one of which is for Mageia; that’s what’s breaking the transaction.

In general, to figure out what packages are required for an offline installation, you should start from your baseline, and [run](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/10154)

```
sudo yum install --downloadonly --downloaddir=<directory> <package>
```

which will download all the required packages to the named directory.

In Ansible’s case, you’d follow [the installation instructions for RHEL 7](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/installation_guide/intro_installation.html#installing-ansible-on-rhel-centos-or-fedora):

```
sudo subscription-manager repos --enable rhel-7-server-ansible-2.9-rpms
mkdir /tmp/ansible-packages
sudo yum install --downloadonly --downloaddir=/tmp/ansible-packages ansible
```

This will download all the requirements to `/tmp/ansible-packages`. You can then copy the packages to other systems (assuming you have the appropriate number of units in your RHEL subscription) and install them using `yum localinstall`.